# Is there a way to stop the execution of current request and call another function using javascript / C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am exporting reports which contains huge amount of data and it takes lots of time to export,
so I am calculating the time duration for export, if it taking more than 60 seconds or the timer goes above 60 seconds then want to export that report in background. by stopping current export request.

Hope you will get my query and help me. Thank you so much

Comment: How do you call the exporting and do you call it in C# or jQuery, because you most likely want to cancel it with the same language?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

why stop current export request?

suggestion:
communicate with your server in async ajax, thus not blocking your client side.
show a blocking user interaction
(like http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)
until one of the following:

1. your calculation say it will take > 60 sec
2. time passed > 60 sec
3. server responded

if 1 or 2 happened - you don't cancel the original processing. its just continuing in the background and your user is free.

the callback from the async ajax will tell the user when it's ready.